# how to check if object is an array of objects

Tags: arrays, swift, object

I have a object like below which is an array of objects.

In swift language, How can i check  whether  object is an array of objects ?

```
 DefinitionList =  (
          {
                    accountNum =          {
                        isEditable = 1;
                        isRequired = 1;  
                    };

                    bAccountType =           {
                        isEditable = 1;
                        isRequired = 0;
                   },

        },                                
        {
                    accountNum =     {
                        isEditable = 1;
                        isRequired = 1;
                    };

                    bAccountType =       {
                        isEditable = 1;
                        isRequired = 0;
                    };
                },

                ..
                ..)
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you're parsing this aren't you pretty much defining this already? Wouldn't the question rather be if you have one or _more_ objects in you array?

Answer (score 0):

Usually i use this in Swift 2 :

```
var  DefinitionList = NSObject?()

    DefinitionList = ["ciao" : "ciao"]

  //  DefinitionList = ["ciao"]

    guard DefinitionList != nil else {

        print("DefinitionList empty")

        return
    }

    guard ((DefinitionList as? Array<NSObject>) != nil)  else {

        print("I'm a Dictionary")
        return
    }

    print("I'm a Array")
```

Swift 3

```
   var  DefinitionList : NSObject?

  //  DefinitionList = ["ciao" : "ciao"] as NSObject

      DefinitionList = ["ciao"] as NSObject

    guard DefinitionList != nil else {

        print("DefinitionList empty")

        return
    }

    guard ((DefinitionList as? Array<NSObject>) != nil)  else {

        print("I'm a Dictionary")
        return
    }

    print("I'm a Array")
```

Comment: I get that cast from myFoundatitionObject Type to unrelated type Array< NSObject> always fail

Answer (score -1):

You can use "is" operator in Swift language.

```
if objects is [AnyObject] {
    print("right, its array of objects!")
} else {
    print("no, its not an array of objects!")
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: this one does not work since my array of objects is custom foundation object and this complais "cast from .. always fail"